# Material on Building a REST api from within a docker container

Tags: rest, docker, go, virtual-machine

I'm looking to build an api on a application that is going to run its own docker container. It needs to work with some applications via its REST apis. I'm new to development and dont understand the process very well. Can you share the broad steps necessary to build and release the APIs so that my application runs safely within the docker but externally whatever communication needs to happen they work out well.

For context: I'm going to be working on a Google Compute VM instance and the application I'm building is a HyperLedger Fabric program written in GoLang.

Links to reference material and code would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

REST API implementation is very easy in Go. You can use the inbuilt *net/http* package. Here's a tutorial which will help you understand its usage. https://tutorialedge.net/golang/creating-restful-api-with-golang/

Note : If you are planning on developing a production server, the default HTTP client is not recommended. It will knock down the server on heavy frequency calls. In that case, you have to use a custom HTTP client as described here, https://medium.com/@nate510/don-t-use-go-s-default-http-client-4804cb19f779

Answer (score 0):

For learning docker I would recommend the docker docs they're very good and cover a handful of stuff. Docker swarm and orchestration are useful things to learn but most people aren't using docker swarm anymore and use things like kubernetes instead. Same principles, but different tech. I would definitely go through this website: https://docs.docker.com/ and implemented on your own computer. Then just practice by looking at other peoples dockerfiles and building your own. A good understanding a linux will definitely help with installing packages and so on.

I haven't used go myself but I suspect it shouldn't be too hard to deploy into a docker container.

The last production step of deployment will be similar for whatever your using if it's docker or no docker. The VM will need an webserver like apache or nginx to expose the ports you wish to use to the public and then you will run the docker container or the go server independently and then you'll have your system!

Hope this helps!